# OS agnostic terminal

Tags: bash, process, terminal

Basically we have a process, spawned from command line which runs in a separate window. (Just ssh, if it matters). The command we use right now breaks on linux:

`osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"foo\"'`

I can use, `xterm -e "foo"`, but that still seems too explicit.

Is there just something that says run this in new window?

**Must work on Mac and Ubuntu**, wider scopes appreciated. Also, minimal configuration please. I'd like to keep it a one liner.

Comment: There is no standard, to my knowledge, of a graphical standard like the POSIX standard for operating systems and shells, so the available terminal applications are necessarily site-dependent. The best you can do is make it a configuration option.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/how-to-launch-an-application-with-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu) on Unix.SE. TL;DR there's no standard way but you can call `x-terminal-emulator` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @larsmans, I am looking for a cross-platform solution not cross-desktop.

Comment: @AaronSchif: there is no cross-platform standard for this.